# Haskell Index Offline Documentation

Tags: haskell, documentation, offline

I'm in the process of generating a Haskell documentation set for Dash (http://kapeli.com/dash).

I'm trying to index the documentation found at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/index.html, and there seems to be a complete index at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/doc-index-All.html.

However, there seem to be a lot of libraries (base, ghc and haskell2010 are some I found), libraries which duplicate the same functions (as far as I can tell).

Which libraries should I index? What would you expect to find in a Haskell documentation browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cross-reference against `base`. The other libraries such as `haskell2010` only exist to provide stable standards against older versions of the language. `ghc` is a developer library only, that I wouldn't expect you to be targetting.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two different issues here.

## Which modules to index?

Well, if you manage to index the whole [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org), and keep your system convenient to use with so many functions, that'd be cool and very useful.

Otherwise, you can restrict yourself to the packages in [Haskell Platform](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/index.html).

## Function duplication

In Haskell modules can re-export entities (functions, types) defined in other modules. This is not specific to base vs haskell2012.

I don't know what interface you provide in your docs browser, but you could display all modules in which the entity is found. This is what Hoogle does: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int (see the first entry there).

Comment: Not sure about what my system's limit is, I've tested it with around 100k entries and it still worked well. The interface is able to handle duplicate entries and allows switching between packages. Currently I've finished indexing the 'default' packages. I guess I could do the entire hackage, but wouldn't that be annoying as users would have to filter through all the extra packages to get to the default ones?

Comment: Whether it'd be annoying depends on the user interface, I guess. But being able to access documentation is at least as important for non-core packages as it is for core packages.